# Empty LWC datatable after adding infinite loading

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, wire, scrolling

Can somebody take a look why my LWC datatable is empty after adding infinite scrolling? I feel that is small bug inside my code, but I am not sure where is it..

JS:

```
    //SHOW WORK ORDER RELATED RECORDS IN DATATABLE
    @wire(getWoliList,{ woid: '$recordId', limitSize: '$rowLimit', offset: '$rowOffset' })
    wiredWOLIS(result) {
        this.wiredResult = result;
        const { data, error } = result;
        if(data) {
            let nameUrl, assetUrl, prodUrl;
            this.wolis = data.map(row => { 
                nameUrl = `/${row.Id}`;
                assetUrl = `/${row.AssetId}`;
                prodUrl = `/${row.PricebookEntryId}`;
                return {...row , nameUrl , assetUrl , prodUrl} 
            })
            this.error = null;
        }
        if(error) {
            this.error = error;
            this.wolis = [];
        }
    }


//enable infinite scrolling


loadMoreDataHandler(event) {
    const { target } = event;
    target.isLoading = true;

    this.rowOffset = this.rowOffset + this.rowLimit;
    refreshApex(this.wiredResult)
        .then(() => {
            target.isLoading = false;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error refreshing Apex', error);
            target.isLoading = false;
        });
}
```

HTML:

```
 <div style="height: 400px;">
                <lightning-datatable data={wolis}
                                     columns={columns}
                                     key-field="id"
                                     onrowaction={handleRowAction}
                                     onrowselection={getSelectedRecords}
                                     enable-infinite-loading
                                     onloadmore={loadMoreDataHandler}
                ></lightning-datatable>
            </div>
```

APEX:

```
    public class woliDatatableRelatedRecords {

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<WorkOrderLineItem> getWoliList(id woid, Integer limitSize, Integer offset){
        

        List<WorkOrderLineItem> woliList = [Select Quantity, PricebookEntryId, LineItemNumber, WorkOrderId, Parent_WOLI__c, AssetId, Device_Name__c, Asset.Name, Product_Name__c
FROM WorkOrderLineItem
WHERE Parent_WOLI__c = false AND WorkOrderId =: woid   
                                           LIMIT :limitSize
                                           OFFSET :offset];
return woliList;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to make sure you initialize the variables for rowLimit and rowOffset, and you don't need to worry about refreshApex, since the parameters are changing. I'd say it's probably better to use a property for the loading flag, too.

```
  @api recordId;
  rowLimit = 100;
  rowOffset = 0;
  wolis = [];
  isLoading = true;
  //SHOW WORK ORDER RELATED RECORDS IN DATATABLE
  @wire(getWoliList, {
    woid: "$recordId",
    limitSize: "$rowLimit",
    offset: "$rowOffset",
  })
  wiredWOLIS({ data, error }) {
    if (data) {
      this.wolis = [
        ...this.wolis,
        data.map((row) => ({
          ...row,
          nameUrl: `/${row.Id}`,
          assetUrl: `/${row.AssetId}`,
          prodUrl: `/${row.PricebookEntryId}`,
        })),
      ];
      this.error = null;
      this.isLoading = false;
    }
    if (error) {
      this.error = error;
      this.wolis = [];
      this.isLoading = false;
    }
  }
  loadMoreDataHandler(event) {
    target.isLoading = true;
    this.rowOffset = this.rowOffset + this.rowLimit;
  }
```

```
<lightning-datatable data={wolis}
                     columns={columns}
                     key-field="id"
                     onrowaction={handleRowAction}
                     onrowselection={getSelectedRecords}
                     enable-infinite-loading
                     is-loading={isLoading}
                     onloadmore={loadMoreDataHandler}
></lightning-datatable>
```